# Linux Touch Directory Command

Tags: command-line, directory, touch-command

What does the command 'touch' when applied to a directory?

```
$ mkdir test
$ ls -l test
drwxrwxr-x 2 dragos dragos 4096 Oct 27 18:08 test
$ touch test
$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 2 dragos dragos 4096 Oct 27 18:08 test
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated [in the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/touch.1.html), the primary use of `touch` is this:

> Update  the  access  and modification times of each FILE to the
>   current time.

So it updates the access and modification times of the directory.

Answer (score 4):

The example at the top doesn't make it clear that "touch" sets the time of the directory (the new time in the listing was the same as the original, simply because the touch was so soon after the directory was created)... yes, the definition of "FILE" in the documentation does include directories, so you can use touch to change their timestamps, BUT...

There are some situations where you cannot change a directory's timestamp (for some types of remotely-mounted directories) even if you have permission to do anything else. e.g. this NFS mount:

```
$ touch -d "2014-07-02 12:15" /public/test.dir    
touch: setting times of ‘/public/test.dir’: Operation not permitted
```

Also, you can get into problems with some old dates not being supported on some servers, e.g.:

```
$ mkdir  /Acer/kopies/test.dir
$ ls -ald /Acer/kopies/test.dir
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark aitchison 0 Mar 11 17:40 /Acer/kopies/test.dir
```

This works:

```
$ touch "2014-04-01 00:00" /Acer/kopies/test.dir
$ ls -ald /Acer/kopies/test.dir
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark aitchison 0 Apr  1  2014 /Acer/kopies/test.dir
```

This would work on a local dir but gives a strange date under Samba mounts:

```
$ touch -d "1955-07-02 12:15" /Acer/kopies/test.dir
$ ls -ald /Acer/kopies/test.dir
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark aitchison 0 Nov 26  60410 /Acer/kopies/test.dir
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2):

> `touch` is a standard Unix program used to change a file's access and
>   modification timestamps. It is also used to create a new empty file.
>
> The Single Unix Specification (SUS) specifies that touch should change
>   the access times, modification times, or both, for a file. The file is
>   identified by a pathname supplied as a single argument. It also
>   specifies that if the file identified does not exist, the file is
>   created and the access and modification times are set as specified. If
>   no new timestamps are specified, touch uses the current time.
>
> -Wikipedia

You can find more in-depth information on the `touch` command (or any other command you would like to know about) by using the `man` command like this:

`man touch`

Answer (score 2):

The immediate reason for the question is the fact that the default time resolution of `ls -l` is in minutes, so a filesystem entry touched within the same minute will show up exactly the same in the default `ls -l` output.

The solution to this is described at https://superuser.com/questions/355318/how-to-have-linux-ls-command-show-second-in-time-stamp
and basically involves running `ls -l --time-style=full-iso` instead.